# How to take screen shot of mapbox and send it to fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

I have been working on a Mapbox based Android app. One is the step is to take a screenshot of the map-mostly surrounding the area of the location Pin dropped by the user-and show that onto the fragment which opens once the location pin is dropped on the map and the user clicks on "confirm" FAB. So far I have figured the part to send the bitmap of the screen shot. But currently, I am see the else condition being executed that is a Toast is created with following exception:

```
[maps-android\Mbgl-Renderer]: Could not take map snapshot because map is not ready yet.
```

This, I don't know possible as at the point where I am taking the screenshot the Map is loaded and a location pin is dropped. I tried googling it and got suggestions to use `getMapAsync` but this method is no longer available. Here is the part of `MapsActivity.kt` where it is executed.

```
private fun setPinActions(pointAnnotationManager: PointAnnotationManager) {
        confirmPinFab.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        cancelPinFab.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        confirmPinFab.setOnClickListener(
            View.OnClickListener {
                pointAnnotationManager.annotations.forEach {
                    it.isDraggable = !it.isDraggable
                    savePinLocation()
                    confirmPinFab.visibility = View.GONE
                    cancelPinFab.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            })
        cancelPinFab.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            pointAnnotationManager.annotations.forEach{
                pointAnnotationManager.delete(it)
            }
            confirmPinFab.visibility = View.GONE
            cancelPinFab.visibility = View.GONE
        })
}

private fun savePinLocation() {
        mainActionFab.visibility = View.GONE
        mapView.snapshot{
            snapShot ->

            val bitmapFragment = PinDetails()

            // Display the bitmap in the fragment
            if (snapShot != null) {
                val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                snapShot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
                val byteArray = stream.toByteArray()

                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putByteArray("mapSnap", byteArray)
                bitmapFragment.arguments = bundle
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't take snapshot", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
        val ft: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        ft.replace(fragementHolder, PinDetails())
        ft.commit()
}
```

This is how `mapView` is initialized:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)

        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView)
        mainActionFab = findViewById(main_action_fab)
        addPinFab = findViewById(add_pin_fab)
        addPinTextView = findViewById(add_pin_text)
        myLocationText = findViewById(user_location_text)
        confirmPinFab = findViewById(confirm_pin_fab)
        cancelPinFab = findViewById(cancel_pin_fab)


        addPinFab.visibility = View.GONE
        addPinTextView.visibility = View.GONE
        myLocationText.visibility = View.GONE
        confirmPinFab.visibility = View.GONE
        cancelPinFab.visibility = View.GONE


        locationInitHelper = LocationInitHelper(WeakReference(this))
        locationInitHelper.setMapView(mapView)

        mapView.getMapboxMap().loadStyleUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS)

        locationEngine = LocationEngineProvider.getBestLocationEngine(this)

        locationPermissionHelper = LocationPermissionHelper(WeakReference(this))

        isAllFabsVisible = false

        onMapReady()
    }
```

I was using a `Framelayout` to replace with the fragment content:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragementHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Can anyone help figure the reason the screenshot is not being taken and sent to the fragment?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragementHolder) This line is returning null.

Comment: @AbdullahJaved Updated the question for more clarification.